# Can you mix indexed signature and base types?

Tags: typescript

My issue is as follows.

```
export type Action = {
    title: string;
    onClick: (item: any) => any;
    to: (item: any) => string;
    icon?: string;
}
export type TableActions = {
    header: string;
    read?: Action;
    edit?: Action;
    permissions?: Action;
    delete?: Action;
    [key: string]: Action;
}
```

Having it like so, gives me this error:

```
Type '{ header: string; }' is not assignable to type 'TableActions'.
  Property 'header' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Action'.
```

Is it possible to combine string or other types, even other "nested" types and also use indexed signature?

Comment: What is `TableActions['header']` used for and would it make sense to separate it from the actual map of Actions like `{ header: string; actions: { [key: string]: Action | undefined } }`?

Comment: it is the title of the actions for the table to render that come in that object, so it makes sense to have them in the same object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't really do that. The signature forces all other properties on the object to match that type, which isn't the case on you object.

An idea to get around this is widening the type of the signature to a [Union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types):

```
export type TableActions = {
  header: string;
  read?: Action;
  edit?: Action;
  permissions?: Action;
  delete?: Action;
  [key: string]: Action | string | undefined;
};
```

Or add another nested object level to group all properties of the same type (or at least similar type) E.g.:

```
export type TableActions = {
  header: string;
  actions: {
    [key: string]: Action | undefined;
    read?: Action;
    edit?: Action;
    permissions?: Action;
    delete?: Action;
  };
};
```